# Biased random walk - stationary distribution

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a modified random walk on the integers such that at each hop movement towards origin is twice as likely as movement away from origin.

[random walk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84b8q.png)

At origin, there's equal probability of staying there, moving to +1, or -1.

Show that a stationary distribution of the form π<sub>k</sub> = cr<sup>|k|</sup> exists, and determine
the values of r and c.

Comment: can you show some work you've tried or provide some context please?

Comment: i've started thinking in the direction that MC is irreducible and aperiodic (self loop). And as a stationary distribution has to exist, it's positive recurrent.

Now, we can find the expected no of steps to return back to a state as time -> infinity.

But I'm not sure on how to find the no of steps to return back to a state.

We can split it into 2 cases, returns in even no of steps and odd no of steps.

Odd case happens only when '0' self loop is traverses odd no of times.

Even case happen only when '0' self loop is traversed even no of times.

Comment: @Snared , do you have idea how to go about this further>

Comment: deleted my comments since I just had to reread your question

Comment: I realised the we could also use induction by using the probability transition matrix itself.

But I'm not sure now how to solve the linear equations using induction